# Table with rounded corners and alternating colors

Tags: css

I can't seem to get this to work. I am trying to create a table with rounded corners and alternating row colors. I trying to round the top border for the first tr in the thead element and the last tr in the tbody.

Here is my CSS so far:

```
.table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

    .table td {
        padding: 7px;
        border: #4e95f4 1px solid;
    }
    /* provide some minimal visual accomodation for IE8 and below */
    .table tr {
        background: #b8d1f3;
    }

        .table thead tr:first-child {
            -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
            -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
            -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
            -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
            border-top-left-radius: 5px;
            border-top-right-radius: 5px;
        }
        /*  Define the background color for all the ODD background rows  */
        .table tr:nth-child(odd) {
            background: #b8d1f3;
        }
        /*  Define the background color for all the EVEN background rows  */
        .table tr:nth-child(even) {
            background: #dae5f4;
        }

        .table tbody tr:last-child {
            -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
            -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
            -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
            -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
            border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
            border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
        }
```

**Edit 1:** Here is the HTML. It is a smart-table, a module based on AngularJS.

```
<table st-table="displayedCollection" st-safe-src="aggregateData" class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Deptp</th>
            <th>Val_desc</th>
            <th>Std_per_lb_rate</th>
            <th>TareF</th>
            <th>QuantityP</th>
            <th>WeightP</th>
            <th>CostP</th>
            <th>Tare_CostP</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="row in displayedCollection">
            <td>{{row.Deptp}}</td>
            <td>{{row.Val_desc}}</td>
            <td>{{row.Std_per_lb_rate}}</td>
            <td>{{row.TareF}}</td>
            <td>{{row.Quantityp | number:0}}</td>
            <td>{{row.Weightp | number:2}}</td>
            <td>{{row.Costp | number:2}}</td>
            <td>{{row.Tare_Costp | number:2}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a certain issue as the background is still extending past the border. My solution is provided below:

CSS

```
table#t01 
{
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 2px;
}

table#t01 thead th {
  background-color:#006400;
  color: white;
  text-align:left;
  padding: 5px;
}

table#t01 tbody td {
  color: black;
  padding: 5px;
}

table#t01 tbody tr td:first-child,
table#t01 thead tr th:first-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 6px !important;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 6px !important;
}

table#t01 tbody tr td:last-child,
table#t01 thead tr th:last-child {
  border-top-right-radius: 6px !important;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 6px !important;
}

table#t01 tbody tr:nth-child(odd) td {
  background-color: #E0EEE0;
}

table#t01 tbody tr:nth-child(even) td {
  background-color: #90EE90;
}

table#t01 tbody tr:hover td {
  background-color: #3D9140;
}
```

HTML

```
<table id="t01">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th> title</th>
            <th> title</th>
            <th> title</th>
            <th> title</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td> cell</td>
            <td> cell</td>
            <td> cell</td>
            <td> cell</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td> cell</td>
            <td> cell</td>
            <td> cell</td>
            <td> cell</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td> cell</td>
            <td> cell</td>
            <td> cell</td>
            <td> cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> cell</td>
            <td> cell</td>
            <td> cell</td>
            <td> cell</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I simply added the alternating color styles to odd and even rows' cells instead of odd and even rows.
I changed the color scheme a little.

Answer (score 0):

Well, a couple of errors. and no HTML so I'll go with some random basic table here:

1. remove the dot from the table in the CSS `.table` should be `table`
2. Remove the `border-collapse` to allow for your table border to show the `border-radius`. See code below

Now you have this:

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th> title</th>
            <th> title</th>
            <th> title</th>
            <th> title</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td> cell</td>
            <td> cell</td>
            <td> cell</td>
            <td> cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> cell</td>
            <td> cell</td>
            <td> cell</td>
            <td> cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> cell</td>
            <td> cell</td>
            <td> cell</td>
            <td> cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> cell</td>
            <td> cell</td>
            <td> cell</td>
            <td> cell</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-spacing: 0px;
}

table td, table th {
  padding: 7px;
  border: #4e95f4 1px solid;
}

/* provide some minimal visual accomodation for IE8 and below */
table tbody tr {
  background: #b8d1f3;
}
table thead tr{
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}
table thead tr th:first-child {
  -moz-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
}


table thead tr th:last-child {
  -moz-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}

/*  Define the background color for all the ODD background rows  */
table tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #b8d1f3;
}

/*  Define the background color for all the EVEN background rows  */
table tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: #dae5f4;
}

table tbody tr:last-child td:last-child {
  -moz-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}

table tbody tr:last-child td:first-child {
  -moz-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}
```

See the [**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/LOTUSMS/pen/ZQyXQX)

Comment: Tried this but the background is still extending past the border. Also I would prefer a way to do this without cutting out `border-collapse: collapse` because I dislike the double borders.

Comment: I just left the office. If no one answers it by later tonight I'll fix it for you. There are other ways

Comment: I edited my answer and demo. You still need to remove the border-collapse, but use border-spacing 0 instead to eliminate the padding that gives you double borders. If this doesn't work in your website is because I am coding against a plain HTML. I have no idea what your looks like.

Comment: As long as the demo shows the desired result, the answer is correct. If its not, doodle a picture and edit your question

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided by sayaksan is what worked for me. Coloring the actual cells and not the rows seems to do the trick.

The other answer provided hid the problem by using too light of background colors to notice the background color bleeding over past the border.

Yes, I know this is a 5 year old post but I spent a long time still trying to solve for this in 2021.

Comment: Marked it as the answer. Hopefully, it'll help out the next person easier.